# Having ajax rendering multiple messages in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf

In this example

```
<f:ajax event="blur" render="errorsID">
            <h:inputText  id="nameID" value="#{tempName}">
                <f:validateLength minimum="2"/>
                <f:converter converterId="upCase"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:inputText id="emailID" value="#{tempEmail}">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]"/>
                <f:converter converterId="lowCase"/>
            </h:inputText><br/>
            <h:messages id="errorsID" errorStyle="color:red"/>
        </f:ajax>
```

I have the latest error message in real time but never both, as soon as i make an email error it displays that overriding the name error and vice versa, but if i remove the **f:ajax** component and use a **h:commandButton** to refresh, i have both the errors properly displayed. Do i need to use a different event ?

Comment: did you try to move the h:messages ?!?

Comment: You should use f:ajax tags inside inputs, not around them. If you put them around inputs, they are attached to the first component up the tree that has an ajaxbehavior feature and supports the blur event (most likely a 'form' tag.